# почему во второй строке ловит NullPointerException?

Tags: java, list

````
List<Position> longest = longestAvailableMoves(2, !lastColor);
            if (longest.isEmpty() && from.inBounds(board.size()) &&
                    !board.get(from).isEmpty() && board.get(from).color() != lastColor)
                legalPos = getMoves(from);
            else for (Position strike : longest)
                legalPos.addAll(getMoves(strike));```
````

Comment: Потому что какое-то поле в той строке является `null` и когда вы у того поля обратитесь к его атрибутам (через `.` точку), то будет такое исключение

Answer (score 0):

Судя по коду, который вы предоставили, longest у вас не имеет атрибута .isEmpty. Поэтому, когда вы пытаетесь обратится к нему, выдает ошибку.